# Is ω really the first ordinal transfinity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

The Internet claims that ω is the first ordinal transfinity. But what about ω-1? Isn't that a ordinal transfinity, and isn't it before ω? Kind of like ω/2?

I guess I lack an understanding of what ω is maybe? Is it equal to some set of numbers, some cardinal transfinity? Is it smaller then any infinite set of numbers? Or is it larger? Or does it even make mathematical sense to say ω<,=,or>ℝ (for example). And if it doesn't, is there some flaw in our theories of transfinity, to the extent of that some comparable numbers cannot be compared to other comparable numbers?

Comment: ω is a limit ordinal, hence ω - 1 is undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by transfinity. Can you supply a reference?

Comment: @ZacharySelk "transfinity" seems to mean "the transfinite". It isn't a standard phrase, but it actually has a certain ring to it.

Comment: See my comments below Clive Newsfeed.

Comment: Oh and by the way, why would someone have disliked my question? I thought it was VERY straightforward. VERY. What qualified me for a loss of reputation? Pertinence? That is subjective, very subjective, and if I believed asking this question was 100% meaningless i would not have asked it. I apparently don't understand something here.

Comment: As for your reference, i got most of my knowledge of it from Wikipedia, i guess the rest is speculation i am trying to harmonize with fact.

Comment: Your posting is more about picking a fight than about trying to learn something.  It is valid to ask how ordinal numbers, and $\omega$ in particular, are defined.  It is not valid to demand why things like $\omega - 1$ are "100% meaningless" unless you can point to a definition.  One might as well demand to know whether $\sqrt \omega$ is smaller than $\omega/2$.  Without having definitions, such requests are meaningless.

Comment: @JacobJ You didn't ask for references to books etc, but you might enjoy reading Halmos' Naive Set Theory. It is one of the all-time classics of mathematical exposition. I am afraid a confrontational approach is unwise on this site, you just attract closure votes (which matter more than reputation downvotes). As I write this you have accumulated 3 (none of them mine).

Comment: I have to give you a definition? I am the one asking what ω is. If it doesn't have a definition already then it doesn't exist to begin with.

Comment: I will lool into that book. Any specific things in it I can focus on?

Answer (score 3):

The ordinals have well-defined notions of successor, addition or multiplication, but not of predecessor, subtraction or division. So while it makes sense to talk about $\alpha + 1$ or $\alpha \cdot 2$ or so on, when $\alpha$ is an ordinal, it doesn't (always) make sense to talk about $\alpha - 1$ or $\frac{\alpha}{2}$, and so on.

The ordinal $\omega$ is simply the first ordinal that is greater than all the finite ordinals. There is no greatest finite ordinal, and $\omega$ is not the successor of any ordinal, so $\omega - 1$ is not defined. Likewise, there is no ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\omega = \alpha \cdot 2$, and so $\frac{\omega}{2}$ is not defined.

When formalised in set theory, the ordinals are usually encoded as [von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals), meaning that $\omega$ is identified with the set of natural numbers.

It doesn't make sense to say $\omega < \mathbb{R}$ or $\omega = \mathbb{R}$ or $\omega > \mathbb{R}$, or whatever else, at least with the conventional meanings of the symbols $<$, $=$ and $>$, since $\omega$ is an ordinal but $\mathbb{R}$ is not. However $\mathbb{R}$ *is* an ordered set... you could define the notation '$\alpha \le X$', for ordinals $\alpha$ and ordered sets $X$, to mean that there is an order-embedding of $\alpha$ into $S$. In that case it would be the case that $\omega < \mathbb{R}$, since the natural numbers are embedded in the reals. But this really is just notation and not any kind of deep and subtle statement about the universe.

I don't know what you mean when you say *transfinity*, so I don't think I can help with your remaining questions.

Comment: Okay. So if ω-1= Ø, then Ø+1= ω. But it doesn't, because Ø operated by anything is Ø still.

Comment: Transfinity- An uncountable number that is not unsurpassable. (Absolute) Infinity- A uncountable number that is also unsurpassable.

Comment: If ω is a pure value, and ℝ is a pure value, then why can't we compare the two values? We aren't comparing apples and oranges here.

Comment: Regarding first comment: saying an expression isn't defined doesn't mean it's equal to the empty set (or anything else, including whatever Ø meant in your comment), it just means the expression doesn't refer to a mathematical object. We can't reason mathematically about $\omega-1$, because $\omega-1$ isn't a thing in the first place! Regarding the other comments: you're using a lot of words that don't have mathematical definitions, at least not conventionally. What does unsurpassable mean? What is a pure value? It seems like you're appealing to intuition without making precise what you mean.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. 5 is a pure value. 5 apples is not a pure value. All numbers and mathematical phenomena are comparable in charge (i mean positivity, negativity, neutrality, and maybe the distincton of reality and imaginariness) and magnitude (i mean absolute value). What is unsurpassable? It means it cannot be surpassed. ∞ is so big it is bigger then itself, (which causes me to believe it is a self-contradiction therefore a nonexistence, which is why i am interested in transfinities). Infinity+1=infinity. Transfinity+1> transfinity.

Comment: Why doesn't ω -1 make no sense? What about it doesn't make sense? If there is a transfinite number of atoms in the universe, and you split one of them, there are now ω-1 atoms in the universe. There is one less even though there is still more then what can be counted. This is similar to the situation of a ω # of atoms in the universe, and we create a new one with energy or whatever. If that was possible, then we would have ω+1 atoms in the universe. It sounds to me subtracting from ω has just as much practical application if not more then the inverse.

Comment: @JacobJ Are you familiar with the proof that, if I remove one element from a countably infinite set, the result has the *same number of* (not fewer) elements? (Look up "Hilbert's Hotel.") This is why you shouldn't expect a good notion of subtraction for infinite cardinals (or ordinals - note that what you're talking about is really **cardinal** arithmetic, whereas **ordinals** are a bit different). I suggest you read an introductory text on ordinals and cardinals - I think it will clear things up nicely.

Comment: That is with infinity, not transfinity. Infinity added to anything (real positive) is still infinity. But transfinities are different. Transfinity added to anything is that same anything added to the transfinity. There is no reason for subtraction to not work the same way. Yeah obviously transfinity subtract 1 or even a million to the millionth power still goes on forever, but it is a different value. As far as I understand, ω can be thought to be found on another number line, because when adding to it and such, it operates like a complex number. Nobody has explained to me why i am wrong yet.